# What are the Gnostic Gospels and why are they not part of the Bible?

Tags: bible, canon, gnosticism

Lately, I have been hearing a lot about the Gnostic Gospels and their more (relatively) unorthodox references to Jesus and a believers relationship to God.

What are the Gnostic Gospels and why are they not part of the Bible, since some of them seem to be written by the same people who wrote passages in the New Testament?

Comment: Ultimately because Gnosticism and Christianity are two distinct religions. Though the former was highly syncretistic, interacting with either paganism, Judaism, or Christianity, it was not, properly speaking, a sect of either of the other three, but rather an independent expression of faith. What all four shared in common (pagan Platonism, Hellenized Judaism, Johannine and Pauline Christianity, and Gnosticism itself) was a significant amount of influence by Greek philosophical thought.